# Oracle ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, go

I try to use golang and query data from Oracle. My SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 OFFSET 10 ROWS;
```

But it gives an error:

```
EXTRA *errors.withStack=dpiStmt_execute: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

My SQL query works fine when I query in SQL*Plus, but errors when I use golang.

Comment: That syntax was introduced in Oracle 12c. So maybe Golang is using an older Oracle client? I'm afraid I don't know anything about Golang so I can't help you further, but with luck this might be enough of a clue for you to diagnose your Golang configuration.

Comment: Not familiar with that client, but is it possible you just need to remove the semicolon?

Comment: Try to remove the `;`

Answer (score 6):

I'd try running the query **without** the terminating semicolon, as Alex Poole pointed out. A lot of Oracle client libraries (i.e. `cx_Oracle` in python, ADO.NET Oracle Libraries) do complain if you try to execute a query ending with the semicolon (which is perfectly legal in SQL/Plus)

Answer (score 0):

If the offset is not specified, it is assumed that it is 0 (zero). So, remove that clause (as it does nothing in your case), i.e.

```
select * from table1
```

and use that query in golang.

Comment: Imagine the offset wasn't zero. The OP's actual problem is that a statement which runs in SQL\*Plus doesn't run in golang. So that's what they need help in fixing.

Comment: My suggestion is right on the track of your commend under the OP's question, @APC - golang he uses doesn't recognize 12c syntax. If offset wasn't zero (well, *if* ... but it *is* zero), then omitting that clause might help in running a query.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that just your closing semicolon is to much. The semicolon is a character to separate several SQL statements or to close a pl/sql block. So when you write it at the end of a SQL statement the parser doesn't know how to handle it, cause he only awaits a single SQL statement.